# Android calling preferences from another class

Tags: android, preferences

I just managed to delete my last question by accident so here it is again.

I have the below class which I chucked together to test the preferences class. The problem I am facing is that when I pass or call from the preferences class nothing happens. The code compiles fine but I'm unable to get or set my preferences. It appears to be getting stuck on `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);` as I have used some print statements to see where it stops. I have tried the using the example on the android site but that does not help. Anyone got any ideas?

```
public class Preferences extends Activity{

public void getSetPrefs(){

    Preferences p = new Preferences();

    p.setLocationPref("london", "1");

    String location = p.getLocation();
    String location_id = p.getLocation();

}
}
```

//Preferences class

```
public class Preferences extends Activity{

    /** Sets location preferences */
public void setLocationPref(String location, int location_id){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("location", location);
    editor.putInt("location_id", location_id);
    editor.commit();
}

/** Get location from preferences */
public String getLocation(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String location = sharedPreferences.getString("location", "");

    return location;
}

/** Get location ID from preferences */
public int getLocationID(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int locationID = sharedPreferences.getInt("location_id", 0);

    return locationID;
}
}
```

Comment: try posting in meta. You can probably get a mod to roll it back

Comment: As I asked in your previous question, is there a reason you're not using getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)?

Comment: Yea sorry deleted it, didn't mean to. Just reading up on them. If you get a simple example that you know of I would be grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

I always retrieve preferences with a call like below:

```
String location = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("location", "");
```